# ACF: How to get sub field in category.php page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have created fields for terms using ACF. I have also created `category.php` using the below code:

```
<?php

// load all 'category' terms for the post
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );

// we will use the first term to load ACF data from
if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {

    $term = array_pop($terms);

    if ( have_rows( 'page_banner' ) ) :

        // loop through the rows of data

        while ( have_rows( 'page_banner' ) ) : the_row();

            $custom_field = get_sub_field( 'small_title', $term );

            echo $custom_field;

        endwhile;

    else :

    endif;

}

?>
```

But I am not getting the results, Need your help. Thank you.

Comment: The second argument of get_sub_field() is not terms. It is the format value,
get_sub_field($sub_field_name, $format_value);

Comment: Sorry Sagar I can't understand. could you give more detail

Comment: When you are calling the get_sub_field(), you are passing $term. But according to documentation, the second argument should be format_value. You can check it here. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the following code. Use the following code.

```
<?php

// get the current taxonomy term
$term = get_queried_object();

if ( have_rows( 'page_banner', $term ) ) {
    while( have_rows( 'page_banner', $term ) ) {
        the_row();
        the_sub_field( 'small_title' );
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Reference

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/

Comment: @VenkateshSrikanth Pleasure is all mine. :)